# Powershell script to list group membership

Tags: powershell

I have written the below script to list all users who are "contractors"`(employeetype=contractors)` and not part of a particular group like "domain contractors" But it is not working, can some one help :)

```
$adusers = get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "OU=test,dc=domain,dc=com" -properties employeetype | where {($_.employeetype -like "contractor") -AND ($_.enabled -eq $true)} 
foreach ($aduser in $adusers){ 
    $contractorsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'domaincontractors').DistinguishedName 
    Get-ADUser $aduser -LDAPFilter "(!(memberof=$contractorsDn))"
}
```

Comment: $adusers = get-aduser -filter *-searchbase "OU=test,dc=domain,dc=com" -properties employeetype | where {($_.employeetype -like "contractor") -AND ($_.enabled -eq $true)} 

foreach ($aduser in $adusers)
  {
     $contractorsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'domaincontractors').DistinguishedName
     Get-ADUser $aduser -LDAPFilter "(!(memberof=$contractorsDn))"
  }

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you tried along with any error messages.

Comment: Do not put your code in comments - put it in your question instead and use the `{}` tag on it.

Comment: I have added the code into the question but the issue remains that you do not explain what is wrong? What is happening and what are you expecting?

Comment: Hey matt, Thanks for editing question.I am trying for an outpu of all contractors who are not part of that group, instead i am getting list of all contractors

Answer (score 0):

$users = get-aduser -filter {(employeetype -like "contractor") -AND (enabled -eq $true)} -searchbase "dc=domain,dc=COM" -properties employeetype
$group = "Domaincontractors"

$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

ForEach ($user in $users) {

```
If ($members -contains $user) {
  write-host "$user exists" -ForegroundColor Red
```

} Else {
    write-host "$user doesnt exist" -ForegroundColor Green
}}